# CakePHP - CakeDC Plugin Permission Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakedc

I have been using the following plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/users) for CakePHP, but I can't figure out how to get the permissions working for it. I have followed all instructions, but it seems `authorize` does not get used at all. Wondering if anyone has any tips on how to make it work. Here is my setup:

**bootstrap.php**

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
```

**AppController.php** `initialize` function

```
$this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');
```

**config/users.php**

```
$config = [
    'Auth' => [
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?'
    ]
];

return $config;
```

**config/permissions.php**

```
return [
    'Users.SimpleRbac.permissions' => [
        [
            'role' => '*',
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => ['display'],
            'allowed' => true
        ], [
            'role' => '*',
            'controller' => 'Taxes',
            'action' => ['*'],
            'allowed' => true
        ], [
            'role' => '*',
            'prefix' => 'v1',
            'controller' => '*',
            'action' => '*',
            'allowed' => true
        ]
    ]
];

return $config;
```

Frankly it seems a CakePHP configuration issue, but I am not able to find where that problem is coming from. I say that because even though debug shows the correct file loaded to `authorize`, it does not get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure you are returning the `$config` variable in the `users.php` file and you are initializing the plugin correctly as indicated here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
```

I've created a test environment here with your provided Auth configuration and it works correctly https://ide.c9.io/steinkel/users-so-42523209

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/790695/girguwv9x7rttdvu5c4x

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I will review what you did here. I failed to add all code on my question and I have updated it to reflect what I have.

Comment: I have reviewed your C9 setup and it seems similar to mine. On your `permissions.php` file, you are allowing `'role' => 'user',` to access the homepage. Based on your screenshot it is preventing access to unauthenticated users. I see the same result in my app even when I have `'role' => '*',`. Could you change that permission in your app to `'role' => '*',` and let me know if you are able to view the homepage, or if it continues sending you to the `login` page. Thank you!

Comment: I mistakenly thought SimpleRbacAuthorize.php would overall allow me not to use $this->Auth->allow(['action']) without a user being logged in. That is not the case. Thanks again!